# How can some users earn more than 73k reputation points a year despite the daily reputation cap?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Stack Overflow has a limitation that one can not earn more than 200 reputation points in a day from upvotes. In this way one can get maximum 73000 reputation points in a year.

The top profiles have 800K+ reputation points. But in the last year, the maximum reputation points earned was 35K+.

If one earn average 50K reputation points in a year, after 10 years, he/she should have 500K+ reputation points.

So how did they earn more reputation points? Is it all from bounties and answers acceptance? Or is there any other reason?

Comment: The cap from upvotes didn't exist in the early days of SO. Early adopters of SO gave some of the Q&As we still to this day consider canonical. And they were damn good back then too. That can translate to a *huge* gain in reputation prior to the cap being put in place.

Comment: "But in the last year, maximum reputation earned 35K+." - No, that's the top reputation earned *in the year so far*.

Comment: @StoryTeller: No, that's not true. The rep cap has certainly applied since late September 2008 when I joined, and I believe it was there from the start - or perhaps applied retroactively when the cap *was* introduced. Could you give an example of a user you believe has a "huge gain in reputation prior to the cap being put in place"?

Comment: @JonSkeet - I cannot, since that comment was made from my own imperfect recollection, with no user in mind. Nor would I name anyone, for the faint risk of putting any unwilling user on the spot. I'll take your word for it.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: *[How to get over 200 reputation points every day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8086)*

Answer (score 18):

According to [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation):

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from the combination of upvotes, downvotes and suggested edits. But [Bounty awards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), [accepted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), and [association bonuses](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/08/cross-site-account-associations/) are not subject to this daily reputation limit.

You aren't *actually* limited to gaining 200 reputation a day. The top users tend to get a lot of acceptances and bounty awards, thus allowing them to gain more than 73000 reputation a year.

Comment: I think the real answer is *accepted answers* - see the [linked-to cross-site duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382378/how-can-some-users-earn-more-than-73k-rep-a-year#comment684820_382378). There aren't that many (consistent) bounty hunters (though that would be the only way to beat Jon Skeet).

Answer (score -16):

I think you are confusing a lot of things. The 200 rep per day is meant to do with upvoting of user's posts. If you get upvoted to guarantee that then your reputation points will increase at the rate of 200 per day as for the upvotes.

Other than that, the people with enormous reputation are most probably getting it out of bounties and the system could be rewarding them.

Comment: I know and mentioned it in the question. My question was if they were earning extra reputations from bounty and acceptance or any other method.

Comment: The system does not reward anyone with reputation points automatically. All reputation points are awarded directly as a result of other users voting on your posts or otherwise performing an action (awarding a bounty, approving an edit suggestion, etc). The only exceptions are you accepting an answer to your question (which awards you 2 points), and downvoting someone else's *answer* (which costs you 1 point).

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: I guess with the other exception being the one-off 100 point association bonus.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, and also offering bounties is a way to affect your reputation without added actions from other users